# Issue with forward propgation in softmax regression model

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use softmax regression to classify 2D data points into either 0 or 1.

```py
import csv
import torch
import numpy

data_path = "C:\\Users\\bchen\\Downloads\\2d-2class-dataset.csv"

data_numpy = numpy.loadtxt(data_path, dtype=int, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

data_torch = torch.from_numpy(data_numpy)

row_count = data_torch.size()[0]
training_count = 16

training_xy = data_torch[:training_count, [0, 1]]
training_labels = data_torch[:training_count, 2]

test_xy = data_torch[:training_count + 1, [0, 1]]
test_labels = data_torch[:training_count + 1, 2]

class Softmax(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(n_inputs, n_outputs)

    def forward(self, x):
        pred = self.linear(x)
        return pred

model_softmax = Softmax(2, 2)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model_softmax.parameters(), lr=0.01)

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Loss = []
epochs = 100
for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    model_softmax.train()
    xy_pred = model_softmax(training_xy) #ISSUE
    loss = criterion(xy_pred, training_labels)
    Loss.append(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(Loss)

with torch.inference_mode:
    y_pred = model_softmax(test_xy)

print(test_labels)
print(y_pred)
```

I'm not too sure what is wrong with my code. I have initialized my Softmax regression model to take in 2 inputs and return 2 outputs. In my training loop, I've tried inputting my training data which consists of a column of x values and a column of y values into my model.

```
print(training_xy)

tensor([[ -85,   40],
        [ -18,   82],
        [-154,  150],
        [ 140,  162],
        [ 102,   64],
        [  22,   28],
        [ 126, -108],
        [ 171,   52],
        [ 276,   43],
        [  77,  -63],
        [ 251, -196],
        [  52, -201],
        [ 181,  -30],
        [  32,  -22],
        [ -34, -129],
        [ -77,  -60]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Could my issue be related to training_xy? Here is my entire csv file

```
# x,y,label
-85,40,1
-18,82,1
-154,150,1
140,162,0
102,64,0
22,28,0
126,-108,0
171,52,0
276,43,0
77,-63,0
251,-196,0
52,-201,0
181,-30,0
32,-22,1
-34,-129,1
-77,-60,1
-127,-207,1
-244,-63,1
-189,60,1
-48,198,1
73,214,0
217,221,0
-72,-248,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types of your input data and model parameters do not match. When converting to the correct data types everything should work:

```py
# convert to the expected data types
training_xy = training_xy.to(dtype=torch.float)
test_xy = test_xy.to(dtype=torch.float)
training_labels = training_labels.long()

Loss = []
epochs = 100
model_softmax.train()  # only needs to be called once, not every epoch
for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    xy_pred = model_softmax(training_xy)
    loss = criterion(xy_pred, training_labels)
    Loss.append(loss.item())  # convert to number that is not part of any gradient calculation graph
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print(Loss)

with torch.inference_mode():  # missed brackets
    y_pred = model_softmax(test_xy)
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional comments as well!